# Discord.py How to mention user?

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a code that sends a message when someone react and it works but I would like the user that reacted to be mentioned and I tried to do it as you can see here below but it dont work.

```
   @bot.event
    async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user_id):
      livechannel = bot.get_channel(1015516535223242762)
      user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
      if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
        await livechannel.send("@" + user + " *is cool!*")
```

Comment: `usert`, maybe typo of `user` ?

Comment: @GokulNathKP I typed wrong but thats not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `ctx` as mentioned in Peter's answer, you can simply use the `user` object provided in the `on_reaction_add` event handler like so:

```py
import discord

# ...

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.Member | discord.User):
    livechannel: discord.TextChannel = bot.get_channel(1015516535223242762)
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
        await livechannel.send(user.mention + " *is cool!*")
```

Comment: When Im trying to use your code I get this error: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'ABCMeta' and 'ABCMeta'

Comment: @Jellie yes, my linter seems to complain about the same thing, however when running the code it appears to work. A workaround is to just remove the type annotation or leave it as either `discord.Member` or `discord.User`, since both classes have a `mention` property.
Also, be sure to remove the "@" before the mention since it's added automatically.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention the author, use

```
@bot.command()
async def pingtest(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(981973830325116998)
    author = ctx.author.mention
    await channel.send(author + " is cool!")
```

If you want to mention another user:

```
@bot.command()
async def pingtest(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(981973830325116998)
    pingmention = member.mention

    await channel.send(pingmention + " is cool!")
```

Please note that the ping may won't work if the mentioned user does not have permission to that channel. I hope it helps!

Comment: I want the bot o mention the user in a specific text channel: livechannel = bot.get_channel(1015516535223242762)

Comment: That's not how you mention another member. You already have `member` as an argument, which automatically converts an ID, a mention or the member's name into a `Member` object. Just use `member.mention` to mention the member, instead of iterating through `ctx.message.mentions`

Comment: @puncher I know that the member argument is useless, but I have copied this code from one of my bot's code that works this way. Your sulution works as well

Comment: @PeterTill I have a already posted message in a channel with a reaction on it. And I want the bot to send a message in another channel when the user reacted.

Comment: @Jellie It is just an example which uses mentions. Of course you can add a logic with if to get when the user is reacted to the message.